# Weird character encoding in Firefox

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with character encoding in Firefox. When I copy/paste a paragraph from Microsoft Word (2007), it could contains special character like this (dots/squares to make a list or quote) :

```
   Te’st
   Ze’f
•   Gzg’a
```

The quote `’` is different compared to this quote `'` (typed directly using keyboard). So I paste this in a textarea and save (using AJAX in some case). In the database (which has a collation latin1_swedish_ci) it shows perfectly fine. But when getting these data to edit again using Firefox, it shows weird binary symbols. Works fine in Chrome and IE.

I don't want to modify the charset of the database. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Note: you can also test by viewing this post in Chrome and FF

Comment: Charset of the database will need to be changed (probably to UTF-8). AFAIK there is no other way around this that won't lose some of the information.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, you could store the data in a BLOB column - but why can't you just change the charset?

Comment: Changing the charset of the database means to risk to have information lost because of the conversion. But the problem here is Firefox... I'm thinking about making a script to convert weird characters into iso8859 charset

Comment: If that is an acceptable solution, what you are looking for is [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 0):

The characters you copypasted (assuming they got transmitted correctly into this forum) contain, in addition to letters, three occurrences of U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, which is the correct punctuation apostrophe in English and many other languages, one occurrence of U+2022 BULLET, which sounds ok, and two occurrences of U+F0A7, which is in the Private Use (PU) range and should not be used public information exchange, only for special purposes by mutual agreements between interested parties.

It is possible that some notations in Word 2007 documents get converted to PU characters in copy and paste, but at least normal list bullet normally becomes U+2022 BULLET. So it is a bit of a mystery where the PU characters come from.

Regarding single quotes, they are representable in windows-1252 too, and [latin1_swedish_ci](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.latin1_swedish_ci.html) seems to cover it (though it is, as far as I understand, just the definition of collating order, rather than a character encoding). And as you are saying that the data looks fine in the database, it seems that problem is in the way in which the data is written in an HTML document served to the browser.

In particular, if the encoding of the page in which the data is then presented is UTF-8 and the actual data is there in windows-1252 encoding, problems arise. It would mean a problem like the one you describe, as U+2019 is encoded as 0x92 in windows-1252, and this causes a character-level data error when interpreted as UTF-8.

You can check the situation by using View→Encoding in Firefox when viewing the result page. If my hypothesis is correct, you will see UTF-8 selected there, and changing it to “West European (windows-1252)” makes the single quote appear (and may mess up other things on the page thoroughly).